# How to pass String[] in retrofit header android?

Tags: android, retrofit

My requirement is to pass String array in header. When I try to pass the below line in request:

@Header("imageId") String[] imageId

My header is sent as following:

imageId: 1703
imageId: 1702

instead of [1703,1702]

Can anyone please help me on how to pass String[] in Retrofit Header? Thank in advance.

Comment: Combine the strings yourself and use `String`, not `String[]`, in the `@Header`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
 @Header("imageId") List<String> imageId
```

or this(depends on yor api):

```
 @Header("imageId[]") List<String> imageId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried these options. Did not work so had to follow Commonsware answer. It worked. But we had to change to body so that it is straightforward.